# have apim pass subscription info to back end service

Tags: apim

I am setting up an API in APIM with "subscription required". It will pass the requests on to a back-end service, using `set-backend-service`.

I would like my back-end service to be able to know which subscription was used to authenticate with APIM.  I don't want the subscription key itself, but rather the `Name` (or `Display Name`) of the subscription that is associated with the subscription key that was used.

What is the best way to pass this name to the back-end service?